# Facet with subplot in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have code that produces facet plots in Plotly with HTML tools. You can see the code below :

```
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

legend <- list(orientation = "v", y = 1, x = .85)

fig1 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("orangutans1", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 1, 3),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "blue"),
  legendgroup = "1"
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend, 
         title = 'Title 1')

fig2 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 84, 32),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "royalblue"),
  legendgroup = "2"
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend,title = 'Title 2')

fig3 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(5, 14, 27),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "green")
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend,title = 'Title 3')

fig4 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(22, 24, 67),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "black")
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend,title = 'Title 4')

htmltools::div(
  crosstalk::bscols(
    fig1, fig2
  ),
  crosstalk::bscols(
    fig3, fig4
  )
) |>
  htmltools::browsable()
```

[image]

Output from this model actually combines four interactive charts and puts them in one place. So I have four charts instead of one, and I can't export them properly (e.g., export as PDF). The main reason for this combination with htmltools is to legend beside each chart. In this way, one problem was solved, but a new problem arose that I explained before.

So can anybody help me how to make a new facet on the bases of **subplot** in the Plotly environment with a legend beside each chart (not a legend in one place for every four plots)?

Comment: There seems no built-in option [Plotly subplots with individual legends](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-subplots-with-individual-legends/1754/18)

Comment: It's a pity that this has been resolved